# Count unique values based on criteria in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I m trying to count the unique values in column A based on criteria - "Blue" of column B. the answer should be 3 but i get 1. the answer should be an excel formula, no array formula or vba.

**Formula:**

`=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(A1:A12,A1:A12, B1:B12, "Blue"),0))`

**Data:**

```
A   Blue
B   Red
C   Green
B   Blue
B   Red
C   Green
B   Blue
B   Red
C   Green
C   Blue
B   Red
C   Green
```

Comment: Hi, add your table as data in the question, as well as your formula. I'm looking at this now for you

Answer (score 0):

So `=COUNTIFS(A1:A12,A1:A12, B1:B12, "Blue")` is doing the following

- Look in: A1:A12
- For value (array): A1:A12
- Also look in: A1:A12
- For value: "Blue"
- Then count

You'll only ever get 1 here because the lookup of A1:A12 will always be A1:12 - AKA 1 = 1

Where anything "Unique" is requested, an Array formula is almost always needed

Comment: What answer do you get?